# %x[] never finishes - ant or sinatra or Windows causing it?

Tags: ruby, command-line, ant, windows-xp, sinatra

I call ant command in my ruby script (on Windows XP) using %x[]. I need to change working directory so the ant starts in the right one. So there two dos commands called.

```
cmd = "cd #{$testing_root_directory.gsub("/","\\\\")} && ant -lib lib -f \"#{$testing_root_directory_builds.gsub("/","\\\\")}\\#{params['group']}\\#{params['run']}_build.xml\" 2>&1"
```

and the content of variable cmd looks like

```
cd C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\ && ant -lib l
ib -f "C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds
\basics\login_build.xml" 2>&1
```

Which is correct and `output = %x[#{cmd}]` works just well.

---

Now I needed to add new target name when calling ant. So I changed the code to accommodate that. See the `#{$target_name}` at the end of the line.

```
cmd = "cd #{$testing_root_directory.gsub("/","\\\\")} && ant -lib lib -f \"#{$testing_root_directory_builds.gsub("/","\\\\")}\\#{params['group']}\\#{params['run']}_build.xml\" #{$target_name} 2>&1"
```

then puts cmd gives me correct output

```
cd C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\ && ant -lib l
ib -f "C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds
\basics\login_build.xml" aftertaf 2>&1
```

But now `output = %x[#{cmd}]` never finishes. There are two targets in my ant file. I can clearly see that the first one finished (default one) and when I quit my ruby script by CTRL + C I can see that the second one (aftertaf) was about to start. There is its label one the screen.

If I use content of the second cmd variable, the one that **doesn't work from ruby**, and run it directly from **DOS command line it works fine**. So it seems to me that ruby is not passing the string right way. cmd.inspect gives me `"cd C:\\Program Files\\TestPro\\TestPro Automation Framework\\ && ant -lib lib -
f \"C:\\Program Files\\TestPro\\TestPro Automation Framework\\Output Files\\buil
ds\\basics\\login_build.xml\" aftertaf 2>&1"`

I guess I can reorganize my ant targets to make my script work but I'd like to know why %x[] never finishes now.

---

- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- on Windows XP

## UPDATE 1

My `aftertaf` target looks like

```
<target name="aftertaf" depends="taf" description="after TAF ruby stuff">
  <exec executable="ruby.exe">
    <arg line="C:\EduTester\others\afterant.rb update_latest 10.0.0.50:4567 basics login 20110803111432"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

When running cmd from `system()` the ant run stops at the `aftertaf` target. There is a aftertaf: label and that's it.

## UPDATE 2

When I press CTRL+C I get asked `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` which I believe comes from ant. I added echo before and after exec in target aftertaf and the echo before exec is executed.

Using full path to ruby.exe in exec didn't help

## UPDATE 3

My ruby script is a sinatra application. I didn't know that it matters. It looks like does matter. If I call above `%X[]` from 'normal' rb file it works. If I call it from sinatra the exec from second target is not executed. Ant batch file is waiting for something. If I remove the exec tag from the new target everything works fine. Note that the **exec works** if ant is run from **.rb** or **command line** or **.bat** file. If I run the same .rb or .bat from sinatra **exec doesn't work**.

Comment: FYI, `exec` will definitely never return. It replaces the current ruby process with the executed process. `system` would run the child process and resume once the child completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here because I don't have a Windows machine available to test at the moment, but is your command stuck waiting for some input?

I notice a couple of differences between the inspect and the puts. In the inspect version:

- There's a space between the '-' and the 'f' before the xml file parameter
- The build target is different. It is 'aftertaf' in this case.

You could try running your command using `system` instead of `%x[]`. That way, instead of being captured, ant's output will be sent to stdout in the console and you can see what's happening.

Comment: Updated my question. The build target should be 'aftertaf', my mistake. I don't think that the extra space matters because the build file specified after f was read and execution started.

Comment: Maybe when running ant from ruby I need to specify full path to ruby.exe file in my 'aftertaf' target....

Comment: What happens if you hit Ctrl-D in the console while aftertaf is waiting? (If ruby is running without command line arguments, it's waiting for you to enter a script in stdin, terminated by Ctrl-D. That's what happens if you just run ruby.exe in the shell.)

Comment: Also, you might want to try splitting up your command line in the ant task, and using <arg value="..."/> for each arg instead of putting them all in one <arg line="..."/>

Comment: That "Terminate batch job" implies that a batch script is running. It could be ant's entry point, or it could be a wrapper for the ruby interpreter. If you call a batch script from within another batch script, it never returns. It works like exec in ruby. To have batch invoke another batch script and return when it completes, you must use "call subscript.bat". What's the full path to ant? Do other ant targets return?

Comment: When I had only target everything worked fine. Now I added new target with exec and the second (new) target is not executed. To be exact the target is executed but the exec.

Comment: please check out Update 3. Some interesting findings out there....At least for me :-)

Comment: Maybe try either `call ant` in your cmd in the ruby script, or use `call` as your exec target in the ant file and put ruby on the arg line. Or both.

Comment: Accepted bacause of the effort @Nick put in.